# Google sheets: freeze the contents of a cell when the date is reached

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with two tabs [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w-KpmczcVMRAxXSbUhxBrG5vesWSf-w1b2KinEpAKdE/edit#gid=1559512930).

First tab has three columns: date, base value, target value.
Second tab has two columns: date, precipiation. That second tabs imports data automatically everytime the sheet is refreshed and only ever has 15 lines of data, meaning that past precipitation data disappears after a while.

The target value is based on base value and can be either optimistic or pessimistic depending on the precipitation on the corresponding date of both tabs. If a corresponding date is not found (using index match), it defaults to optimistic.
Since past precipitation data disappears, past target values default to optimistic. All of this is done without user input.

Is there a way to lock the target value once today is reached? I want the pessimistic values to remains pessimistic even if the corresponding date disappears from the second tab. I would like the target value to remain unlocked until today's date is reached since weather predictions are most accurate close to the date.

Comment: Kindly do add your samples in form of text, so that we can test our formulas/codes, thank you.

Comment: [access denied](https://i.imgur.com/DGXVL72.png), Please share the sheet with [Everyone with the link](https://i.imgur.com/Oh4SUnW.gifv), second are you open to a script solution?

Comment: Bear in mind that sharing the spreadsheet will expose the name of your Google account, people opening the file will be able to see your name in Google Drive, as well they might find  your email address.

Comment: I don't think so. You would have to persist the target values in the first sheet somehow, every time before the data is imported.

Comment: @Osm my bad, it should be shared now. I would be very grateful for a script solution actually!